# Restoring non-autorenewing purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

Does the app have to offer to restore non-autorenewing subscription purchases (the way it is required with one time purchases) or should this be implemented through the "infrastructure" that Apple requires us to build for sharing purchases among different devices?

I ask because in  testing mode, when I try to Restore this type of transactions, I get an empty list back from Apple.

Thanks in advance!

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per response on the Apple Developer's forum, non-renewing subscriptions are not restorable.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide non-autorenewing subscription
below 5 was provided by the apple
1. Consumable
2. Non-Consumable
3. Auto-Renewablesubscriptions
4. Free subscriptions
5. Non-Renewing subscriptions 
on which one you are working on.